# Gibt es »auf glatte Bahn geraten«?

Tags: idiom

Ich weiß schon, dass *auf die schiefe Bahn geraten* ein Ausdruck ist. Ich weiß auch, was er auf englisch bedeutet.

Aber ist *auf glatte Bahn geraten* auch ein Ausdruck? Wenn ja, was bedeutet er? Ich habe diesen Ausdruck in Thomas Manns *Buddenbrooks* gesehen.

Comment: Ein üblicher Ausdruck ist *auf's Glatteis führen*. Das bedeutet, dass jemand in eine unsichere Lage gebracht wird. Häufig ist das so gemeint, dass man nach komplizierten Argumenten ein einfaches Gegenargument bringt, auf das der durch die vorigen komplizierten Argumente "auf's Glatteis geführte" keine einfache Antwort weiß. "Auf glatte Bahn geraten" ist sehr sicher davon abgeleitet. Siehe auch *eristische Dialektik*.

Comment: Ja, alles klar. Danke.

Comment: Thomas Mann modifiziert öfter mal stehende Redewendungen. Es kann also eine kreative Neuschöpfung sein, die gerade auf "auf die schiefe Bahn geraten" anspielt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich habe mal Google ngrams befragt.

*auf die glatte Bahn geraten* ist wörtlich nicht zu finden.

*die glatte Bahn* schon eher, dort muss man sich aber den Kontext anschauen.

Die absolute Häufigkeit der Wendung ist nicht so spannend - deshalb habe ich stichprobenartig mal einige Vorkommen genauer angeschaut:

- grob die Hälfte der Fundstellen für "glatte Bahn" verwenden die Wendung nicht im übertragenen Sinn, sondern wörtlich, z.B. für die Eisenbahn, Strasse, oder eine Eis- oder andere "glatte Bahn" im wörtlichen Sinn.
- Der Rest der Fundstellen verwendet "glatte Bahn" als Synonym für "den einfacheren Weg gehen"

  > Du willst das Ideal deiner Seele in Dir selber erstreben und hast dazu die glatte Bahn häuslicher Friedenstage Dir gewählt. *Bettina von Arnim, "Ilius Pamphilius"*
- Oder als Synonym für "glattes Parkett" oder "dünnes Eis" im übertragenen Sinne -

  > ...dabei wohl ausgerüstet mit classischer Bildung ... beschritt Heimburg zum ersten Male ... die glatte Bahn des öffentlichen Lebens... *Der deutsche Cardinal Nicolaus von Cusa und die Kirche seiner Zeit*
- Sehr wenige Vorkommen transportieren dieselbe Bedeutung wie *auf die die schiefe Bahn geraten* (also, sich auf den Weg begeben, mit dem Gesetz in Konflikt zu kommen) auch nur annäherungsweise (hier eher: der direkte Weg):

  > Nein; der unschätz hervorzurufen, die nur zu oft die glatte Bahn zum Verderben sind. (*Paynes Universum*)

Das Vorkommen, das ich in den *Buddenbrooks* gefunden habe, hat allerdings auch nichts mit der **schiefen Bahn** zu tun, sondern eher mit dem **direkten Weg** oder **in Fahrt kommen**.

> »Was ist das«, sprach darauf langsam: »Ich glaube, daß mich Gott«, fügte, während ihr Gesicht sich aufklärte, rasch hinzu: »– geschaffen hat samt allen Kreaturen«, war plötzlich auf glatte Bahn geraten und schnurrte nun, glückstrahlend und unaufhaltsam, den ganzen Artikel daher, getreu nach dem Katechismus, wie er soeben, anno 1835, unter Genehmigung eines hohen und wohlweisen Senates, neu revidiert herausgegeben war.

*die glatte Bahn* ist also findbar, auch wenn sich die Bedeutung "in Fahrt kommen" im modernen Deutsch eher weniger wiederfindet - Nach 1945 finde ich nur noch Zitate von früheren Veröffentlichungen.

Comment: Alles ist nun sehr klar! Danke.